# Unresolved symbol in stacktrace when using GCC 4.8.2's Asan

Tags: gcc, memory, stack-trace, address-sanitizer

I give a try to bug hunting with the help of this tuto : https://fuzzing-project.org/tutorial2.html

When I'm using address-sanitizer, I don't have any symbol resolution on the stack trace.

I try the manipulation describe here : [Meaningful stack traces for address sanitizer in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163828/meaningful-stack-traces-for-address-sanitizer-in-gcc) but it doesn't work for me. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Here are the steps I take :

1. I use a test program in C which is a classic off-by-one-error

   ```
   int main() {
       int a[2] = {1, 0};
       int b=a[2];
   }
   ```
2. I install llvm 3.5 with `apt-get`
3. I export The following variables

   ```
   export AFL_USE_ASAN=1
   export ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.5
   export ASAN_OPTIONS=symbolize=1
   ```
4. I compile with gcc 4.8.2 with the following command

   ```
   gcc -o test -fsanitize=address -g3 -ggdb test.c
   ```
5. There are the warnings I've got in the bug report when I launch the test program. It seems that AddressSanitizer can't connect to llvm-symbolizer-3.5

   ```
   ==13382== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fff92d6b0e8 at pc 0x400845 bp 0x7fff92d6b0a0 sp 0x7fff92d6b098
   READ of size 4 at 0x7fff92d6b0e8 thread T0
   ==13382== WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 3
   ==13382== WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 3
   ==13382== WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 3
   ==13382== WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 3
   ==13382== WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 3
   ==13382== WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 3
   ==13382== WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer
        0x400844 (/media/data/test+0x400844)
        0x7fe5e7d4aec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21ec4)
        0x400688 (/media/data/test+0x400688)
   Address 0x7fff92d6b0e8 is located at offset 40 in frame <main> of T0's stack:
     This frame has 1 object(s):
       [32, 40) 'a'
   HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
         (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
   Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
     0x1000725a55c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     0x1000725a55d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     0x1000725a55e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     0x1000725a55f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     0x1000725a5600: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   =>0x1000725a5610: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 00[f4]f4 f4
     0x1000725a5620: f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     0x1000725a5630: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     0x1000725a5640: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     0x1000725a5650: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
     0x1000725a5660: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
     Addressable:           00
     Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
     Heap left redzone:     fa
     Heap righ redzone:     fb
     Freed Heap region:     fd
     Stack left redzone:    f1
     Stack mid redzone:     f2
     Stack right redzone:   f3
     Stack partial redzone: f4
     Stack after return:    f5
     Stack use after scope: f8
     Global redzone:        f9
     Global init order:     f6
     Poisoned by user:      f7
     ASan internal:         fe
   ==13382== ABORTING
   ```

And I don't get any symbol on the stacktrace.
If I perform a sudo I don't have any warnings but I don't have any symbol resolution either.

```
==13392== ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fff911555e8 at pc 0x400845 bp 0x7fff911555a0 sp 0x7fff91155598
READ of size 4 at 0x7fff911555e8 thread T0
     0x400844 (/media/data/test+0x400844)
     0x7f4721057ec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so+0x21ec4)
     0x400688 (/media/data/test+0x400688)
Address 0x7fff911555e8 is located at offset 40 in frame  of T0's stack:
  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 40) 'a'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions are supported)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x100072222a60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100072222a70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100072222a80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100072222a90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100072222aa0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x100072222ab0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 00[f4]f4 f4
  0x100072222ac0: f3 f3 f3 f3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100072222ad0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100072222ae0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100072222af0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100072222b00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:     fa
  Heap righ redzone:     fb
  Freed Heap region:     fd
  Stack left redzone:    f1
  Stack mid redzone:     f2
  Stack right redzone:   f3
  Stack partial redzone: f4
  Stack after return:    f5
  Stack use after scope: f8
  Global redzone:        f9
  Global init order:     f6
  Poisoned by user:      f7
  ASan internal:         fe
==13392== ABORTING
```

I also try the python script `asan_symbolize.py` describes in the google page project but without any results.

https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/CallStack

Answer (score 2):

I updated to gcc 4.9.
Now it's working.
Here's the step I take in Ubuntu to update.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9
```

More details here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/466651/how-do-i-use-the-latest-gcc-4-9-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> export ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/usr/bin/llvm-symbolizer-3.5
> ...
> READ of size 4 at 0x7fff911555e8 thread T0
>      0x400844 (/media/data/test+0x400844)
>      0x7f4721057ec4 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so+0x21ec4)
>      0x400688 (/media/data/test+0x400688)
> ```

Under ***Clang***, you need to pipe your output through `asan_symbolize` to get the symbols. I discuss Clang because you are clearly using LLVM gear (*llvm-symbolizer-3.5* above). So you should do something like:

```
./test 2>&1 | asan_symbolize
```

I have `asan_symbolize` in both `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ find /usr/ -name asan*
/usr/bin/asan_symbolize
/usr/lib/llvm-3.4/lib/clang/3.4/include/sanitizer/asan_interface.h
/usr/local/bin/asan_symbolize.py
/usr/local/lib/clang/3.5.0/include/sanitizer/asan_interface.h
```

I have two copies because one was installed with Clang via `apt-get` (`/usr/bin/asan_symbolize`), and I build Clang from sources on occasion (`/usr/local/bin/asan_symbolize.py`).

If you have ***no*** copies, then I believe you can fetch it from [address-sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/AddressSanitizer) on Google Code.

---

Once you start using `asan_symbolize`, you might encounter a situation where `asan_symbolize` cannot find the symbols due to a path change (for example, a program or library was copied from its build location to a destination directory). For that, see [Specify Symbol Path to asan_symbolize?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/address-sanitizer/OTzWjoZIfhY/NwdF3FKL5JAJ) on the Asan mailing list.

In *kcc's* answer, he meant to do something like:

```
./test 2>&1 | sed "s/<old path>/<new path>/g" | asan_symbolize
```

(I think I had to do it when testing Postgres).

---

I recently started using GCC's sanitizers, but I have never used `asan_symbolize` with ***GCC***. I'm not sure how well its going to work for you. Naively, I would expect its going to work as expected.

---

> I compile with gcc 4.8.2 with the following command...

I'm not sure how well mixing/matching will work for you. Perhaps you should stick to GCC; or you should install Clang and use it.

---

Python has a crash course in Clang and its sanitizers at [Dynamic Analysis with Clang](https://docs.python.org/devguide/clang.html). It discusses topics like getting stack traces. (I wrote the page for the the Python project to help them add Clang and its sanitizers to its release engineering process).